# Weird rails error while loading the application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I am having this bizarre error and I don't know what to do.

This code runs fine on my development and staging machine but crashes on production.

All I have to do is load the page or call script/server to trigger the following error:

Error message:
interning empty string

Exception class:
ArgumentError

Full Stack trace: [Code](http://pastebin.com/czsfaXvZ)

Sorry for this short description, but this is all that i am able to show to you. =/

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be because you have an invalid filename for a partial (a filename with two consecutive zeros).

For example

```
_partial..html.erb (invalid)
```

This blog post mentions this error:
http://anaphoral.blogspot.com/2009/04/rails-interning-empty-string.html

Comment: thanks for your rapid response, but unfortunately my partials are fine. =(

I am installing ruby-debug now. I hope it can help me figure out what is wrong. =)